# How can i add visual studio build tools in a pyinstaller run?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, cvxpy

I'm trying to develop a minimization alghorithm for master thesis task. I used [cvxpy](https://www.cvxpy.org/install/index.html) and i'd like to make an installer, since it would be very interesting for remaining research group that do not use python. As described in the [installation](https://www.cvxpy.org/install/index.html) documentation, cvxpy need visual studio build tools for python 3.

This complicate the stuff: how can i use pyinstaller and create a directory in which are already embedded also all visual studio dependencies needed for cvxpy? If this is not possible, how can i setup [Inno setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) in order to install visual studio build tools for python 3 before installing my application, taking only the necessary package from visual studio build tools?

Answer (score 0):

Build a bootloader for PyInstaller
Download Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019 from Microsoft.
Run the vs_BuildTools.exe downloaded in the previous step.
Select “C++ build tools”
Install/upgrade setuptools: $ pip install setuptools --upgrade.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance: therefore if i add a buildloader to pyinstaller it automatically create the exe with the visual studio build tools in the directory? i will be able to distribute my app as a separated application?